# irq/51-iwlwifi appears in "top"

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel

While downloading over Wi-Fi, `irq/51-iwlwifi` appeared in `top`, using about 5% (of one core) of my CPU.

So it sounds like an IRQ handler as a kernel thread.  I hadn't noticed cpu usage of this process before.

Is it new?

---

My current kernel build is `5.0.8-200.fc29.x86_64`.  This can also be seen in my `atop` logs, which go back to 2019-03-28 with kernel build `4.20.13-200.fc29.x86-64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see this since commit 2bfb50924c7e, ["iwlwifi: use threaded interrupt handler"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2bfb50924c7e92362ac937aef2ab56bc7bd3ca52).  This change was released in  kernel version 3.9 (2013).

---

(The kernels in the question do not have `CONFIG_IRQ_FORCED_THREADING_DEFAULT` (or `PREEMPT_RT`).  And I do not boot the kernel using the `threadirqs` option.)